# Issues importing librosa on python ImportError: cannot import name 'iter_entry_points'

Tags: python, file, librosa

`import librosa`

This is the line that caused the error. It seems like something that

I am not sure how to fix this error -- it is from just importing librosa :( It seems like this is an error that is from the package itself and not from my code. Any insights would be appreciated.

```
Full traceback: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b8b10328035d> in <module>()
----> 1 import librosa
      2 import numpy
      3 import skimage
      4 import pkg_resources
      5 from setuptools.py31compat import iter_entry_points

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py in <module>()
     10 # And all the librosa sub-modules
     11 from ._cache import cache
---> 12 from . import core
     13 from . import beat
     14 from . import decompose

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py in <module>()
    123 """
    124 
--> 125 from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
    126 from .audio import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
    127 from .spectrum import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/core/time_frequency.py in <module>()
      9 import six
     10 
---> 11 from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
     12 from ..util.deprecation import Deprecated
     13 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py in <module>()
     75 """
     76 
---> 77 from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
     78 from .files import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
     79 from .matching import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/util/utils.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 import numpy as np
---> 10 import numba
     11 from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
     12 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/__init__.py in <module>()
     26 
     27 # Re-export types itself
---> 28 import numba.core.types as types
     29 
     30 # Re-export all type names

AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: Did anything work?